# Fat model, thin controller - but what if mixed models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I am building a Ruby on Rails 4.1 app that has the following models that should make sense when you see the model names:

Domains, Teams, Users, Meetings etc

Now, a Team belongs to a domain and a User to a team, also meetings belong to a user. A domain is simply an organisation or company that is using the software.

After the creation of an admin user that user has to initially create a Domain, then create the first team, then other users can sign up.

As you can probably anticipate, in the process of creating the initial Domain and Team (which is done in the new/create of the Team and Domain controllers) I am having to access and change references in all three. So, for example, creating the first Domain will have to associate the admin user, creating a Team will involve linking it to the user, then also the parent domain.

So, it's all getting a bit mixed up, with the controller needing to access several models.

My question is, where does this logic belong? In the spirit of thin controller you would normally farm it out to the model, but it involves more than one model. Is this where the new Rails 4 concerns become useful or should I just put it in the controller?

I am relatively new to rails, so please keep that in mind if you are kind enough to reply - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Nested resources

```
class Domain
  has_many :teams
end

class Team
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :domain
end

class User
  has_many :meetings
  belongs_to :team
end

class Meeting
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then in your controllers:

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @team = Team.new
  end

  def create
    @domain = Domain.find(params[:domain_id])
    @team   = @domain.teams.build(params[:team])
    @team.save

    respond_with @team
  end

end
```

That's what we call a "nested" controller, in the `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :domain do
  resources :team
end
```

The URL will look like that:

```
/domains/:domain_id/teams
/domains/:domain_id/teams/:team_id
```

Same logic apply for other models. This should give you a starting point to build your application.

The following line

```
@domain.teams.build(params[:team])
```

automatically link a domain to a team setting the reference (`id`) for you.

However you should not do deep nesting according to [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) so that's where the builder design pattern can come in handy.

## Builder design pattern

However, if things start to get to messy, I would suggest using a dedicated ruby class to "build" your objects and their relationship. We usually call those classes a "Builder":

```
class TeamBuilder

  attr_reader :domain, :params

  def initialize(domain, params = {})
    @domain = domain
    @params = params
  end

  def build
    domain.teams.build(params)
  end

end
```

Here it's again doing very simple task. For user and meetings for example:

```
class UserBuilder

  attr_reader :team, :params

  def initialize(team, params = {})
    @team = team
    @params = params
  end

  def build
    team.users.build(params).tap do |user|
      user.foo = 'foo'
      user.meetings.build(...)
      user.meetings << MeetingBuilder.new(user, { ... })
    end
  end

end

class MeetingBuilder
  # ...
end
```

Here we use the `MeetingBuilder` within the `UserBuilder` to build a meeting.

Usage:

```
user = UserBuilder.new(team, { ... }).build
user.save
```

Comment: This is something I considered doing - time to consider it again. Going to take me a couple of hours to evaluate this - thanks Pierre.

Comment: How far would you nest it though? User would seem to fit in this nesting too, but I remember now what my issue with this was. I have about 5 other classes (building, room, attendance, booking, check) which are also interrelated and when I looked at the nesting I thought I could end up with too many nested resources. BUT, I see you stopped at one deep. Could you maybe say if this is a deliberate choice? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you should avoid deep nesting, have a look here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I think the builder option is a better one given that the routing would be too complex, I think even carefully nested, given the number of classes that interact with each other. Thanks for your answer Pierre, which I will accept.

Comment: Where would you put the builder classes in the Rails 4 directory structure? Concerns is split model/controller - so, maybe in a helper directory?

Comment: I would create a `builder` directory in `app` :)

Comment: Just one last question (thanks!): Does that mean that app/builder is included already? I don't have to add any require/include to the top of models/controller?

Comment: Oh, and shouldn't the build method of Teambuilder be: @domain.teams.build(@params) ?

Comment: builders will be included by default (rails require each file in `app` directory by default). the `build` method attached to `teams` is actually the ActiveRecord default method, not your custom builder method :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51828/discussion-between-tentimes-and-pierre-louis-gottfrois)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, a model shouldn't care about, or even know about, other classes. So between the model and the controller, this kind of logic definitely belongs in the controller.

I would probably go with a third class though, taking care of that messy stuff, like a DomainFactory for example. Which is just a plain old ruby object (poro), no active record or anything, with the sole purpose of creating domains.

A tip is to read up on *loose coupling* and *single responsibility*.